# How to determine strip condition of nonlinear PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I started learning PDE on my Own. I was doing Example 0.14 in the book (1) p. 32 but I stuck at one step. I do not understand how the Author come at the conclusion about strip condition.

> **Example 0.14** Find the characteristics of the PDE
>   $$
> p^2+q^2=2
> $$
>   and determine the integral surface which passes through $x=0$, $z=y$.

Here, $p=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $q=\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ (see book (1) p. 24).

[image]

[image]

[image]

I understand everything except strip condition equation 2

Any Help will be appreciated

(1) K. Sankara Rao, *Introduction to Partial Differential Equations*, PHI Learning Pvt. Ltd., 2010. [GBooks Preview](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=RfW_V6pvhf8C&lpg=PP1&hl=fr&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: Dear Sir It is form Introduction of Partial differential equation By K S Rao. Page number 32.Please Help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One has
$$z_0(s) = u(x_0(s),y_0(s))$$
so differentiating with respect to $s$ leads to the so-called *strip condition*
$$ \frac{d z_0}{ds} = p_0 \frac{d x_0}{ds} + q_0 \frac{d y_0}{ds}$$
In your case,
$$ \frac{d z_0}{ds} = 1; \quad \frac{d x_0}{ds} = 0; \quad \frac{d y_0}{ds} = 1$$
so one gets 
$$1 = p_0(0) + q_0(1)$$
(notice that $p_0(0)$ and $q_0(1)$ mean $p_0\times(0)$ and $q_0\times(1)$ here... I don't think it is a good notation). So one gets $q_0 = 1$.

Now you can get $p_0$ from $q_0$ using the fact that
$$p_0^2+q_0^2-2=0$$
that gives $p_0^2 = 1$, i.e. $p_0 = \pm 1$.

*Remark.* The strip condition does not depend on $F$ (here $F(x,y,z,p,q) = p^2+q^2-2$).